# Convert daily data to weekly data and group them by companies

Tags: r, dplyr

I have daily data of stock prices from 2009 to 2020 March and I want to have the last values of the weeks for every month. My data looks like this:

```
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  tarih      stock_code adj_close_price
  <date>     <chr>                <dbl>
1 2020-03-31 SRVGY                10.6 
2 2020-03-30 SRVGY                 9.91
3 2020-03-27 SRVGY                 9.78
4 2020-03-26 SRVGY                 9.04
5 2020-03-25 SRVGY                 8.22
6 2020-03-24 SRVGY                 7.6

> tail(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  tarih      stock_code adj_close_price
  <date>     <chr>                <dbl>
1 2009-01-09 TUDDF                 2.48
2 2009-01-08 TUDDF                 2.46
3 2009-01-07 TUDDF                 2.68
4 2009-01-06 TUDDF                 2.76
5 2009-01-05 TUDDF                 2.68
6 2009-01-02 TUDDF                 2.72
```

And I want to find something like this:

```
tarih   stock_code  adj_close_price
31.03.2020  SRVGY   10,60
24.03.2020  SRVGY   7,63
17.03.2020  SRVGY   8,14
10.03.2020  SRVGY   10,70
...
30.01.2009  TUDDF   2,42
23.01.2009  TUDDF   2,38
16.01.2009  TUDDF   2,44
09.01.2009  TUDDF   2,48
02.01.2009  TUDDF   2,72
```

However, I want to do this for every company in stock_code, I know that I need to group them but I don't know how to extract the dates and then group them.
Could someone help me do that? Thanks and appreciating your response.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: I thought converting them into weekly data: weekly <- data %>% 
    mutate(year = year(tarih), month = month(tarih), week = week(tarih)) %>%
    unite_("date", c("year", "month", "week"), sep ="-", remove = FALSE) %>% 
    group_by(year, week, stock_code) %>% 
    arrange(stock_code)

Comment: However it only got me the number of weeks, not the end values of them. Unfortunately then I got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `stock_code` divide all the dates by 1st date and select the rows which are completely divisible by 7 so that you get the weekly dates.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- data %>% 
            group_by(stock_code) %>% 
            filter(as.integer(x - first(x)) %% 7 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(week = format(tarih, "%V")) %>%
  group_by(stock_code, week) %>%
  summarise(
    tarih = last(tarih),
    stock_code = last(stock_code),
    adj_close_price = last(adj_close_price)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. But the "tarih" column doesn't include more than 2019-02-11 (also sometimes for some stocks it starts on 2015) and looks random and it doesn't match the actual stock prices.

Comment: @CeydaÇaylak You are right, I hadn't noticed that the tarih column is ordered descending. That makes the difference. WIll delete in 1h00 or so.